# REGEX_CONTAINS not functioning as expected in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have an example string type column in Bigquery that contains data like this:

abc_def

or

|def|ggg|abc

And I am trying to capture the abc by using REGEX_CONTAINS(lower(column_name), r'b\abc\b) but the condition returns false as if it's not functioning properly and reading the abc (we've built it this way so that we capture the exact phrasing needed).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a bare minimum, this works. But using REGEXP (not REGEX). `REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(column_name), r'abc')`. What are you trying to do with the "b\".

Comment: Well I was trying to look for the beginning or ending of a word to determine if abc existed.. I think I can do it with simply \b at the beginning... and try to add more criteria

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check beginning and end of string for your matching, below should work

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(column_name), r'^abc|abc\s?$'
```

**Sample testing with output:**

[image]